# AWS CloudFormation: only non-default parameter values in mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Let's say I have a child CF template that takes parameters with default values:

```
Parameters:
  Name:
    Type: String
    Default: whatever
  InstanceSize:
    Type: String
    Default: m3.medium
  InstanceCount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 5
```

I also have a main CF template that takes an "EnvType" parameter. The value of "EnvType" should determine what Name, InstanceSize and InstanceCount must be passed to the child stack. And I only want to have non-default values specified in this mapping. So if "EnvType" is set to "Test", InstanceSize should be "t2.small" and InstanceCount should be 2. If "EnvType" is set to "Production", the child stack's default values for InstanceSize and InstanceCount should be used. I try the following:

```
Mappings:
  ParamsByEnvType:
    Test:
      Name: staging
      InstanceSize: t2.small
      InstanceCount: 2
    Production:
      Name: prod
    Staging:
      Name: staging
    ...

Resources:
  MyChildStack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        Name: !FindInMap [ParamsByEnvType, !Ref EnvType, Name]
        InstanceSize: !FindInMap [ParamsByEnvType, !Ref EnvType, InstanceSize]
        InstanceCount: !FindInMap [ParamsByEnvType, !Ref EnvType, InstanceCount]
    ...
```

This fails with "**Unable to get mapping for EnvType::Production::InstanceSize**" template validation error when the template is run with EnvType = "Production". Which is kind of expected: I do not have a second-level "InstanceSize" key for a top-level "Production" key in "ParamsByEnvType" mapping.

So my question is: is there a construct that would allow me to only keep non-default values in "ParamsByEnvType" mapping (like I do now) and only pass parameters to the child stack when their values are defined in this mapping?

I tried setting a condition like this:

```
Conditions:
  DefaultInstanceSize: !Equals [!FindInMap [ParamsByEnvType, !Ref EnvType, InstanceSize], !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

If fails with "**Every Fn::Equals object requires a list of 2 string parameters**" error.

I also tried this condition:

```
Conditions:
  DefaultInstanceSize: !Equals [!FindInMap [ParamsByEnvType, !Ref EnvType, InstanceSize], ""]
```

It fails with "**Unable to get mapping for ParamsByEnvType::Production::InstanceSize**" error.